# Is it possible to use one specific mysql result as an object ? NodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js

I got my MySQL data printed in console.log() as `console.log(result)` and it works fine.

Now I need to use this result to define variable `MyPlan` in a different function.

This is how I got the results from MySQL db:

```
function load() {
    
    var MySQL = SQL.createConnection(credentials)
    MySQL.connect((err) => {
          if(err) {
             console.log(err);
             process.exit(0);
          }
        
          for(var i = 0; i < 250; i++) console.log('\n');
         console.log('Successfuly logged in!');
          
    });
           MySQL.query("SELECT plan FROM users WHERE username = 'asd123'", (err, rows) => {
               
               if(err) { console.log(`[!] SQL Error: ${err}`); return; }
              
             rows.forEach((results) => {
                    console.log(results); //output: RowDataPacket { plan: 300 }
               });
               
           });
               
}
load();
```

I need `MyPlan:` to be declared with a number `300` as stated above.

```
    startMyPlan() {

        //var theoric = 10;
        this.botCountInt = setInterval(() => {
            let json = {
                connected: 0,
                MyPlan:   //300

            };
            this.send(json);
        }, 100); 
    }
```

I tried to define `results` in first function like this:

```
             rows.forEach((results) => {
            myresult = results //first option
        // OR LIKE THIS:
            this.myresult = results; //second option
                    console.log(results); 
               });
```

and write it in `startMyPlan()` as

```
            let json = {
                connected: 0,
                MyPlan: this.myresult

            };
```

But first option gave me error `myresult is not defined` and second option gave me different error: `Cannot set properties of undefined(setting 'myresult')`.

EDIT: I guess my problem is that `results` won't give me correct output OUTSIDE that function where it's created. It returns `undentified` when I try to run `console.log(results);` once it's run outside `load()` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as per my understanding, you have not defined the `myresult` variable in any scope.
The first option will work if you do `var myresult=undefined` just before `rows.forEach((results) =>`  call.
One example:

```
var rows = [{ "test": "foo1" }, { "test": "foo2" }, { "test": "foo3" }, { "test": "foo4" }];
var myresult;
rows.forEach((results) => {
    myresult = results //first option
    console.log(myresult);
});

console.log(myresult);
```

I am not sure what exactly you want to do with `myresult`. But I think above example will be enough to understand things.

Comment: Okay so I tried to define `myresult`  as you said and it worked.
I am trying to get data from `MyPlan` to display in my tampermonkey extension like this:  https://prnt.sc/cxnu_E4SyyJS (which works if I use `this.myresult = "VIP";`  and then use it in `MyPlan: this.myresult;` )
 but once I try getting result from database with code `this.myresult = myresult;`
I get undefined instead of "VIP" in my site: https://prnt.sc/0kiRZ9Dqruwh

Comment: Sorry if i barelly make any sense but basically, I want my server to identify which plan im using by fetching it from database, instead of definding it manually in the code like `this.myresult = "VIP"`

Comment: BY THE WAY: In previous code I wrote that I want output to be `300` and not `VIP` so you don't get confused...I just put that number in database while testing. So It doesn't really matter is the output `300`, `VIP` or something else. The point is i need that output to be shown in my userscript UI